# numpy.where returning empty index

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

So I'm trying to create two arrays using `numpy`. One array is a lot bigger than the other, so I want to search the large array to see where each element in my small array are located (i.e. what index). However when I run the code below, one of the elements in the small array cannot be found and I'm not sure why. Is it a data type mismatch?

Please advise, thank you!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

GMean = np.array([4.23, 4.93, 5.67, 6.62, 4.67])
conc_x = np.arange(0.0, 90, 0.1)
GMean = np.round(GMean, decimals=1)
for i in np.nditer(GMean):
    spec_index = np.where(conc_x==i) #look for index in conc_x data set where our GMean data point lies
    print i
    print spec_index

console output:
4.2
(array([42]),)
4.9
(array([49]),)
5.7
(array([57]),)
6.6
(array([], dtype=int32),) #why can it not find the index here?
4.7
(array([47]),)
```

Comment: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://www.floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: check with np.close.

Comment: thanks for the info Warren, very insightful but don't see anything that will help me. Wen, i don't see any documentation for np.close(), do you mean np.isclose()? My arrays are different sizes so can't use that unfortunately. I still don't understand how to ensure that both numbers match. Is it a rounding error? What should i do?

Comment: To account for floating point error, it's better to use a < epsilon instead of a == comparison. Instead of `spec_index = np.where(conc_x==i)` , you can put something like `spec_index = np.where((conc_x-i)<1e-10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using `numpy.around()` instead of `numpy.round()` works. I get an index every time. 
I thought they were the same but looking at the documentation, there is a subtle difference:

"Round an array to the given number of decimals."

vs:

"Evenly round to the given number of decimals."

So i'm thinking "evenly round" means it is rounding all trailing digits beyond the desired decimal, and therefore, both numbers you are comparing become exactly the same.

Hope this makes sense.